# How to fix error respone from daemon error when running sail after deleting all containers?

Tags: laravel, docker, directory, composer-php, mount

I'm creating a Laravel/VueJS SPA. All the way, it was working however, just one time running `sail up -d` showed `http://localhost` with `the site can't be reached` error.

I have deleted all containers by running `docker image prune -a` and `docker system prune -a` but `http://localhost` was still showing `the site can't be reached` error.

Then I deleted `vendor` and `composer.lock`, run `composer install` again, installed sail, then run `sail up -d`. After running it I got an `Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path error`. See screenshot of error:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r00Wb.png)

I was attempting to create the folder mentioned but not sure where to create it in mac. Any advise how to fix this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem really related to [tag:composer-php] or [tag:mount]? If yes, please share more details by editing your question

Comment: It is related to running sail of Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by:

1. Run `sail build`
2. Run `sail up -d`

Answer (score 0):

Before delete container, you must stop first

```
docker stop <container IDs | container names>
```

Then

```
   docker rm <container IDs | container names>
```

`docker image prune -a` --> command allows you to clean up unused images

`docker system prune -a` ---> This also will not delete running containers